# Fast way to sort data into different buckets based on cell value to the left

Tags: vba, excel

Here is the problem I am trying to solve.

First I need to run an SQL query. This query returns data that has up to 12 categories, each dependent on the previous. For example, if my input into the query was 'United States', then column 1 would be 'United States', and column 2 would have each of the 50 states. Column three would then have all the major cities. So we end up with about 1000 rows, each with 'United States' on the left, a state in the middle, and the city that the state is on in the third column, like this:

```
 United States   Texas   Austin
 United States   Utah    Salt Lake City
 United States   Nevada  Las Vegas
```

What I need to do is to programmatically create data validation for each of the categories based on the previous columns value.

My current idea is to take the original data, split it out into different sheets two columns at a time, and remove the duplicates. Then I would take the unique values from column A and paste them across the top, and distribute the data from column B into the correct columns. Then I'd make that a table, and make my data validation look at the headers in the table.

The problem comes in here: I don't know how to quickly distribute the data from column B into the correct column.

For clarity, this is what my data looks like on every page, except with thousands of pairs in columns A and B, and I need to distribute it into the three columns quickly.

```
                           Texas     Utah     Nevada
 Texas   Austin
 Utah    Salt Lake City
 Nevada  Las Vegas
```

Here's what I'm working with so far:

```
Num = 1
Col = 6
EndRow = Columns(Col).Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
For Col = 6 To 19
    Set rng = Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(EndRow, Col))
    Unique = CountUnique(rng)
    If Unique > 1 Then
     Set rng2 = Sheets("SQL Dump").Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(EndRow, Col + 1))
     rng2.Copy
     Set ws = Sheets.Add
     ws.Name = "List" & Num
     Num = Num + 1
     ws.Activate
     Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
     'MsgBox ("Do Stuff")
     os.Activate
    End If

Next Col
```

So that splits it into unique sheets as needed based on the two columns. 
If anyone knows of a way to quickly sort, that would be greatly appreciated!

Or if you know a way to solve the problem more efficiently overall, I'd love to hear that, too--thanks!

EDIT: CountUnique is a function that I am using to count the number of Unique values that exist in a column.

Comment: If your data is sorted, then using a combination of INDEX MATCH and COUNTIF/COUNTIFS should allow you to create DV lists without breaking it up further.

Answer (score 0):

This transposes ranges quite easily. is this what youre looking for?

```
Sub TransposeRangeValues()
    Dim TmpArray() As Variant, FromRange As Range, ToRange As Range

    Set FromRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:c4")
    Set ToRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1")

    TmpArray = Application.Transpose(FromRange.Value)
    FromRange.Clear
    ToRange.Resize(FromRange.Columns.Count, FromRange.Rows.Count).Value2 = TmpArray
End Sub
```

Comment: Not quite, I'm looking for something that is more along the lines of the `pivot` function in SQL

Comment: @reggie86 I guess Im confused b/c this pivots the data? Play around with it and  see if it works? Just plug and play with your ranges